# Go to Href <a href=""> From .Cs file function

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to Go to  click but not want to click on link but want to go to from cs file.
Here IS my Code..

```
<a id="editbtn" runat="server" href="#popup_edit">  


 <div  runat="server" style="z-index:2" id="popup_edit" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <h2>Edit Region</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class=" col-md-3  " for="RegionEdit">
                Region Name <span class="">*</span>
            </label>
            <div class=" col-sm-6 ">
                <input type="text" id="RegionEdit" runat="server" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <asp:CheckBox CssClass="checkbox-inline" ID="Active" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="EditReg" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn  btn-round btn-danger" OnClick="EditReg_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this div to pop up from .cs file

Answer (score 0):

First, use jQuery dialog on client-side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPopup()
{
    $(".popup").dialog({
        title: "Pop-up Dialog",
        width: 600, // just example
        height: 400, // just example
        modal: true, // set to false if the popup isn't modal
        // other properties here, including dialog('close')
    });
}
</script>
```

Afterwards, change plain anchor tag to either LinkButton or Button control to trigger server-side `Click` event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="EditBtn" runat="server" Click="EditBtn_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="EditBtn" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" OnClick="EditBtn_Click" />
```

Then, handle `Click` event in code behind .aspx.cs file to point jQuery dialog function above:

```
protected void EditBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Popup", "showPopup();", true);
}
```

Reference: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/05/show-jquery-modal-popup-from-code-behind-server-side.html (with some changes to fit question requirements).

Comment: Acyually I want to popup from gridview row index changing i dont want to click any button . IS there any thing that i can simply go to href from function in .CS file